# How do I create a D3.js tree layout with custom child nodes?

Tags: d3.js

I want to visualize a series of hierarchical bullet graphs. Specifically, I want to be able to click on my top level category bullet graphs, and have them expand into the sub-topic breakdowns with a bullet graph for each sub-topic.

So basically, I want to recreate this D3 tree example: 
    http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

But have each node be a bullet graph instead of just a circle:
    http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/bullet.html

I'm brand new to D3, so even looking at the example source code, I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: That looks kind of interesting. A tree diagram to a chart to another tree branch to another chart. Why not just make the "circle" nodes clickable/hoverable with a popup of the chart you want? Might make your page smaller overall.

Comment: Ha - that would actually work great, and be much easier for me to implement :p  If no one else responds, can I can accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that the canvas acts like a real two dimensional drawing canvas.  You, as the author of the visualization control where you place any object on the canvas.  There are two things you need to worry about... 1) Making sure you have all data that you need to realize a visualization at a specific point on the canvas, and 2) Understanding how to draw your visualization in the way you want to render it, where you want to render it on the canvas.

In the case of mixing charts with the nodes of a tree, the nodes act as reference points for placement of the charts.  You'll quickly notice that the more nodes you have, the more difficult it will be to render your charts because of canvas clutter.  In other words, you will be dynamically be drawing charts over tree elements (nodes and branches).  You may want to consider something like rendering the chart related to a node in another area of the canvas that does not contend with the tree visualization (such as the upper left or lower left of the canvas).  So, for example, if you hover over a node, the node changes size and/or color and/or shape to show that it is currently "in context" and, simultaneously, you see the corresponding bullet chart (or any other relevant information) in a clear and uncluttered area of the screen (such as in the upper left hand corner of the drawing, away from the branch "sprawl" of the tree, which becomes more and more cluttered, as the tree grows further to the right of the canvas (this assumes a tree that grows from left to right).  Doing so ensures that there is no clutter blocking between any one drawing or any other.  Keeping the bullet chart that is drawn when you hover over a node in an area of the canvas that does not contend with the tree means you won't have to "redraw" the elements of the tree that get blocked out each time the chart draws itself over specific tree elements, which would be the case if you draw the chart "over tree elements".

Anyhow, I hope this helps.

My Best,

Frank